# Cannot access the property value after creation Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My problem is, after I insert several nodes with uri properties of the type:

```
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#Red"
```

Later, I want to extract the part after hashtag (which is "Red" for this case), so I use the split function and create property name with value tail(records):

```
MATCH (n) WITH split (n.uri, '#') AS records, n 
WHERE head(records) = 'http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine' 
SET n.name = tail(records)
```

after successfully creating the property name with appropriate name for a set of nodes, I check (everything perfect for now):

```
 Match (n) Return keys(n)
```

I create a label (concept) for all the nodes:

```
MATCH (n) SET n :concept RETURN n
```

Later trying to access the value of property "name":

```
 Match (n{name: 'Red'}) RETURN n
```

or

```
Match (n:concept{name: 'Red'}) RETURN n
```

I am getting the empty response (obviously it is not connected to label created, as even before I couldn't access it). I would appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TAIL(x)` function returns a *list* (of all values in `x` after the first), not a scalar value. Therefore, the `name` in your example would have the value `["Red"]`, not `"Red"`.

Instead of:

```
SET n.name = tail(records)
```

your Cypher code should have used the following (assuming your `uri` values always embed a "#"):

```
SET n.name = records[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!